# I can't get is_page() & get_header() working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

My code below isn't setting the page 'dashboard' to use my header-dashboard.php Header file. What is wrong?

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}


if(is_page('dashboard')) {
 get_header('header-dashboard.php');
} else {
 get_header();
} wp_head();
```

Comment: First set wp_debug to true in wp-config.php file.

Comment: Without detailed code we cannot properly help, but can you add echo "anything" in IF clause to see which part of if condition is working. Also make sure 'dashboard' is correct slug name and header-dashboard.php is correct filename

Answer (score 0):

I used

include('header-dashboard.php');

instead of

get_header('header-dashboard.php');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).